# Remove link and style from top item of css drop menu

Tags: html, css, drop-down-menu

I am working on a site that has a standard drop nav bar with the first button having a css drop down menu. Everything works fine but I want to remove the link from the top of the drop menu as it does not link to anything, it is just there to drop the menu down. The problem is that it is picking up on the styling of the other items. When the item is hovered over the cursor becomes the finger and the font changes color indicating a link. I do not want it to do either but after trying several different ways I am not able to resolve it!

I tried to do this to remove the finger Portfolio but I don't think that is correct? It also does not stop the text changing color?

I have made a fiddle:  [enter link description here](http://jsfiddle.net/Margate/yfqMv/)

```
    #name {background-image: url("darren-morton.jpg");  width: 600px; height: 90px;     position: absolute; top: 0px; left: 150px;}
     /*Navigation Bar Menu */
    #NavBar{position: relative; top: 70px; left: 288px; width: 645px; height: 30px; z-index: 20;}
    ul#navmenu, ul.sub1 {list-style-type: none; font-size: 14px;}
    ul#navmenu li {width: 80px; text-align: center; position: relative; float: left;}
    ul#navmenu a {text-decoration: none; display: block; width: 80px; height: 25px;      line-height: 25px; background-color: #FFF; border: 1px solid #000000;}
    ul#navmenu li:hover > a {text-decoration: none;}
    ul#navmenu li:hover a:hover {text-decoration: none;}
    ul#navmenu ul.sub1 {display: none; position: absolute; top: 26px; left: 0}
    ul#navmenu li:hover .sub1 {display: block;}
    ul#navmenu .sub1 li:hover {display: block;}
.downarrow {font-size: 11px; position: absolute; top: 1px; right: 2px;}

a:link {color: black; text-decoration: none;}
a:hover {color: #c6000f; text-decoration: underline;}
a:active {color: black; text-decoration: none;}


<div id="NavBar">
<ul id="navmenu">
    <li><a href="#">Portfolio</a><span class="downarrow">&#9660;</span>
        <ul class="sub1">
            <li><a href="travel-landscape-photography.html">Landscape</a></li>
            <li><a href="travel-portrait-photography.html">Portrait</a></li>
            <li><a href="images-of-sadness.html">Sadness</a></li>
            <li><a href="black-and-white-travel-photography.html">Other</a></li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li class="test"><a href="about-darren-morton.html">About</a></li>
    <li class="test"><a href="top-travel-photography-tips.html">101</a></li>
    <li class="test"><a href="contact-darren-morton.html">Contact</a></li>
</ul>
</div>
```

Thank you very much in advance for any help,

Margate

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check this **[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/yfqMv/3/)**

Only 2 things were to be done-

1. Remove the anchor tag enclosing the `portfolio`-tab.
2. Change the following

   ```
   ul#navmenu a {text-decoration: none; display: block; width: 80px; height: 25px; line-height: 25px; background-color: #FFF; border: 1px solid #000000;}
   ```

To

```
ul#navmenu li {text-decoration: none; display: block; width: 80px; height: 25px; line-height: 25px; background-color: #FFF; border: 1px solid #000000;}
```

Comment: That is what I was trying to exactly! I have learned as well, I will not just copy the code and say thank you! I will study it and see where I went wrong in order to learn from this. Thank you very much for your time it has really helped. When I become good as JQ I will contribute back. Margate  :  )

Comment: All the best for that.

Answer (score 1):

Best thing is to NOT MAKE IT AN ANCHOR TAG. However if you must, add the following styling:

```
ul#navmenu li a:first-child {
    cursor: normal;
    text-decoration: none;
    color: black;
}
```

OR add a class to that first link and style it that way. That would be better.

Like this: http://jsfiddle.net/yfqMv/1/

Comment: Hello Leeish, thank you for the fiddle, I have changed the anchor tag removing the href # but am not sure if this will cause a problem or not? Here is the updated fiddle that you made:           http://jsfiddle.net/Margate/gYkWT/          I just wanted to stop the cursor changing to the finder on mouse over...

Comment: Thank you very much. I understand the way you have solved this, I did try to do something like this but just do not know the syntax to well at the moment.

Answer (score 1):

If you don't want it to be a link then just don't make it a link. Changing to `<li><span>Portfolio &#9660;</span>` maintains your functionality and you may style it with `ul#navmenu > li > span` or an id or class.

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Margate/yfqMv/)

Also, don't forget to take [css specificity](http://coding.smashingmagazine.com/2007/07/27/css-specificity-things-you-should-know/) into account

Comment: The link is excellent and just what I need. I knew that I needed to learn something like this but did not know what it was called or even if there was a subject on it! You have hit the nail on the head for me. I will read and bookmark the page in order to learn and keep a reference point. Thank you very much  : )

Answer (score 1):

Updated

You can use normal hierarchy in css like to apply css to Portfolio you can do

```
ul#navmenu > li:first-child > a { cursor: auto; color: black}
```

it `ul#navmenu > li` will select all first li elements i.e no sub menu li element, then t select first li add `first-child` then for only top level `a` elements do `> a`

Check this fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/raunakkathuria/yfqMv/2/

---

You can also use

```
:not(:first-child)
```

to apply css for all other elements except the first child, so you can do

```
ul#navmenu li:not(:first-child)
```

Comment: Thank you very much. This is a help to me and I can learn for this  :  )

Answer (score 1):

**Just simple. if you use anchor TAGS. you have to redefine the style by your own**

```
ul#navmenu li:first-child a {
   color: black;
   cursor: default;
   text-decoration: none;
}
```